# Spring build 4.1.2 is throwing error about missing method setRemoveOnCancelPolicy in ThreadPoolTaskScheduler

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

To get fix of issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16888 (formerly SPR-12283), I upgraded my Spring to version 41.2 after which it complains about missing method setRemoveOnCancelPolicy in ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.

Following reported issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16852 (formerly SPR-12238) points that it is due to JDK 1.6, but I am on 1.7

I am using IBM Java and it's version is java_1.7_64, when I deploy in WebShepre, I get following Exception

```
org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler 
org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurationSupport.defaultSockJsTaskScheduler()] 
threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.ja
```

Comment: You have inconsistencies in your dependencies. Please check versions of Spring artifacts. This is different error from the one on Spring's JIRA.

Comment: I raised an issue here https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12465, have uploaded all the dependency which I am using.

Comment: Issue SPR-12465 was migrated to github spring projects here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17071